# How to suspend one store until January 8th with least SEO damage?

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.1.0, delivery

```
Magento 1.9.1 
Porto theme 
Amasty's delivery date extension (plugin)
```

We have few different stores running off the same Magento 1.9.1 installation. We have the Delivery date extension (a calendar) installed because we hand deliver the product. I have disabled all the days in the calendar until January 8th but a few orders just keep coming through...I cannot duplicate the issue because when I try to place an order without a date - it doesn't let me and when I open the calendar - all the days until January 8th are grayed out (not available). I'm not really sure how these customers are able to place orders?

**Any which way - what is the best way to  make it so people would not be able to order WITHOUT completely destroying our SEO standing?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could disable the checkout, that's not really messing with your content, but it's been my experience, people will still order as long as you let them know orders will not be processed until a certain date.

I put a banner notice at the top of every page saying orders placed will not be shipped until "X" date. I style it to look like the 'demo' store notice.

On the Terms and Conditions, I update to reflect the shipping delay and also added a CMS block into the shipping method container with the same information.

I also make only 1 shipping method available - Flat Rate and and for the title call it 'Shipping Resumes on XX/XX/XXXX' and then whatever you want to call the method name.

Doesn't seem to have much of an effect, if any on SERP. But I do disable any paid ad campaigns during that time. The orders still come in and since the notice is literally on every single page and requires action to verify this, nobody complains.

But if you have surveys or review scripts running on your success page, disable those as well.

Comment: Thanks for these awesome ideas! :o) How do you disable checkout? I need to do this on Magento 2.1.0 also....